# Flutter Error when building: Invalid <color> for given resource value

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

I wanted to change the App icon with the `flutter_launcher_icons` package but after I did `flutter run` I get the following error even though I never edited the File mentioned in the error

This is the error:

```
PS C:\Flutter\appname> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on Pixel 5 in debug mode...
C:\Users\jjkla\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8de94d7eb39fc01aa715c73f850e88dc\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\values\values.xml:5:4: Invalid <color> for given resource value.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             14,3s
```

Part of the File where it says the color is invalid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr format="reference" name="nestedScrollViewStyle"/>
    <color name="androidx_core_ripple_material_light">#1f000000</color>
    <color name="androidx_core_secondary_text_default_material_light">#7E000000</color>
    <color name="notification_action_color_filter">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="notification_icon_bg_color">#ff9e9e9e</color>
    <dimen name="compat_button_inset_horizontal_material">4dp</dimen>
...
```

I reinstalled Android Studio, did flutter clean, updated Java and run flutter doctor without success. Does anyone had this error before?

Comment: Solved here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341977/flutter-error-when-building-for-android-invalid-color-for-given-resource-valu/77381328#77381328](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341977/flutter-error-when-building-for-android-invalid-color-for-given-resource-valu/77381328#77381328)

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove 2 f from both colours? Because the color hashCode length should be 6.

Your file should like this.

```
<color name="notification_action_color_filter">#ffffff</color>
<color name="notification_icon_bg_color">#9e9e9e</color>
```

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately